# Dificuldade em definir operadores RxJS e Stomp

Tags: angular, spring-boot, websocket, rxjs

Estou preso em um problema, não consigo definir o RxJS para atualizar a UI em tempo real conforme as mensagens são enviadas ao websocket.
A conexão está funcionando e as mensagens sendo enviadas ao socket.

```
private connectedUserMessages$: Subject<ChatMessage> = new Subject();   

onConnected(nickname: string, fullname: string): any {
this.stompClient.subscribe(
  `/user/${nickname}/queue/messages`,
  (payload: any) => {
    const newMessage = JSON.parse(payload.body);
    this.connectedUserMessages$.next(newMessage);
  }
);
```

Observables:

```
    getUserMessages(
    senderId: string,
    recipientId: string
  ): Observable<ChatMessage[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<ChatMessage[]>(
      `${this.messagesUrl}/${senderId}/${recipientId}`
    );
  } 

     getConnectedUserMessages(): Observable<ChatMessage> {
        return this.connectedUserMessages$.asObservable();
      }
```

No component eu concateno as mensagens antigas do banco com as novas enviadas com o "map" e faço a manipulação do service no constructor:

```
constructor(private messageService: MessageService) {
    this.messageService.getConnectedUserMessages().subscribe(message => {
      console.log("New message from socket");
      console.log({ message });
      this.addMessageIfNotExists(message);
    });
    this.messages$.subscribe();    
  }
```

Este é o restante da logica de adição de mensagem a interface:

```
    selectUser(selectedUser: User) {
    this.selectedUserId = selectedUser.nickName;
    this.selectedUser = selectedUser;
    this.messages$ = concat(this.messageService.getUserMessages(this.connectedUser!.nickName, selectedUser.nickName),
      this.messageService.getConnectedUserMessages()
    ).pipe(
      scan((messages: ChatMessage[], newMessage) => {
        console.log("scan");
        console.log([messages]);
        console.log({ newMessage });
        if (Array.isArray(newMessage)) {
          return [...messages, ...newMessage];
        } else {
          return [...messages, newMessage];
        }
      }, []),
      map((messages) =>
        messages.sort(
          (a, b) =>
            new Date(a.timestamp ?? new Date()).getTime() -
            new Date(b.timestamp ?? new Date()).getTime()
        )
      )
    );
  }

  addMessageIfNotExists(message: ChatMessage) {
    this.messages$ = this.messages$.pipe(
      map((messages) => {
        const messageExists = messages.some((msg) => msg.id === message.id);
        return messageExists ? messages : [...messages, message];
      }),
      map((messages) =>
        messages.sort(
          (a, b) =>
            new Date(a.timestamp ?? new Date()).getTime() -
            new Date(b.timestamp ?? new Date()).getTime()
        )
      )
    );
  }

  sendMessage() {
    if (this.connectedUser && this.selectedUserId && this.message) {
      const uniqueMessageId = Date.now().toString();
      this.messageService.sendMessage(
        this.connectedUser.nickName,
        this.selectedUserId,
        this.message,
        uniqueMessageId
      );
      const newMessage: ChatMessage = {
        id: uniqueMessageId,
        chat: undefined,
        senderId: this.connectedUser.nickName,
        recipientId: this.selectedUserId,
        content: this.message,
        timestamp: new Date(),
      };
      this.addMessageIfNotExists(newMessage);
      this.message = '';
    }
  }
```

A mensagem de outro User só aparece na UI quando se envia outra mensagem, ou seleciona novamente o mesmo usuário.